# Virtualbox Bridged networking guest to host interaction

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a machine that has Windows 7 as the host OS. I have installed RHEL as the guest OS in this machine using virtualbox. For networking, I have chosen "Bridged networking". According to my understanding, if I use bridged networking, all the guest OS will have different IP addresses and virtual NIC will be bridged to a physical NIC. My problem is,

- When I ping from the host OS to the guest OS, I am able to do it without any problem. However when I try to ping from the guest OS to the host OS, I am getting a timed out error.
- Should the MAC address be the same in both the host OS and guest OS for the interaction between the guest OS and the host OS? If that is the case, how am able to connect to the internet from the guest OS?

Please let me know if my understanding of the bridged networking concept is correct.

Comment: Does your host machine normally respond to pings? It could be blocked in your Firewall settings.

Comment: Yeah. I am able to ping to my guest OS as well as outside networks from my host windows 7 machine.

Comment: But does your host OS respond to pings typically? You mention that you're getting a timeout going from Guest to Host while pinging.

Comment: Yeah. Host OS is responding to pings normally. I tried from another machine in the network and the host machine was responding.